# Tips to enhance the performance of the following simply SQL query

Tags: sql, performance, sap-ase

I would like to receive help in enhancing the performance of my `SQL` query. The query is so simple, but it is taking quite sometime to execute, so I would like some tips on how I can enhance the query:

```
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    SOME_DB_TABLE
  WHERE
    SUBSTRING(TIME, 1, 8)
  BETWEEN
    "20110101" AND "20111231"
  AND
    CONDITION_COL = "C"
  GROUP BY
    TIME
  ORDER BY
    TIME ASC
```

Comment: Do you already have `TIME` indexed? That can help speed up your `SELECT` substantially.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? PostgreSQL? Firebird? Oracle?

Comment: @Palladium, Good point, I do not have TIME indexed atm. I NEED to use `SUBSTRING` on TIME, would indexing that column still be feasible?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I am using Sybase.

Comment: Yes, it is. Indexing doesn't impact the operations you can perform on a column (although it does slow down updates and inserts into said column).

Comment: It depends on the query optimizer, but I think there is a high likelihood that the `SUBSTRING` forces a table scan to evaluate that on every row, regardless of whether or not the Time column is indexed.

Comment: @hatchet: most DBMS allow the creation of an index based on an expression (e.g. substring()). Don't know if Sybase can do that though.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - I didn't consider that. Sybase computed columns may be what the OP needs http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.sqlug/html/sqlug/sqlug387.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The substring function could be slowing your query down.

Would something like the below work?

```
time >= "20110101" 
and time < "20120101"
```

Comment: +1 ... or they could use BETWEEN, but specify the full dateTime of the range.

Comment: @Aaron, I must use the SUBSTRING function because only that part of the string needs to be used and the later parts will actually cause trouble in comparisons.

Comment: Waht else is in that field except the time portion of a data that you claim this won't work? It should work ewell iof all you have is typical datetime data. If you don't have that what do you have?

Comment: @czchlong If the other part is not time, then you would be better off splitting the column into two, since you are storing two different pieces of information in a single column.

Comment: It is also time, but it then takes the form of `H:M:S.mS`. If I do comparisons using these, will that not screw up comparisons? Actually, I will do a quick check now.

Comment: I eliminated `SUBSTRING` as it turned out it won't mess up my comparisons. The query is much faster now. Also, is there a performance difference between using `>= and <=` comparisons and the `BETWEEN` keyword?

Answer (score 0):

You should index the time column like this:

`CREATE INDEX some_index
ON SOME_DB_TABLE (TIME)`

This will make a search on this column way faster.
Also, do you really need every columns ? Using `SELECT *` is

- A bad habbit
- Execution time conssuming if you take non-important columns

Comment: the OP's use of substring over the Time column will likely prevent the use of any index on Time.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to take all columns...but will my manually doing `SELECT` on each column enhance performance over `SELECT *`?